# When does optaplanner produce the resulting xml file?

Tags: java, optaplanner

I want to know if in the `optaplanner NurseRoster` case, the result file will only be generated when `solutionBusiness.terminateSolvingEarly()` is called. If you do not call `terminateSolvingEarly()`, will the result xml file be generated?

Answer (score 1):

Distinguish between `optaplanner-core` and `optaplanner-examples`:

- `optaplanner-core`'s `Solver.solve()` method returns the best solution as java objects in memory. It doesn't care how the solution will be persisted (xml, json, database, ...), that's your problem (which you can learn/copy from `optaplanner-examples`).

  - `optaplanner-core` is a dependency for your code
- `optaplanner-examples`'s persists that best solution with `*FileIO.write(File, solution)`. Some examples write to XML (using `XStreamSolutionFileIO` - nurse rostering does this too), others to Excel, etc. I believe it's `SolverAndPersistenceFrame` and not `SolutionBusiness` that calls the `FileIO.write()`.

  - `optaplanner-examples` is NOT a dependency for your code, you copy paste some of this example code.